# Get text to display based off another reference

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an e-mail subject line, based on data in a cell which references another cell.

For some context, I work for an airline (not in IT you will be glad to know!) and I am trying to create a system which saves us from having to type things out, over and over again!

Desired output.

1. User selects "Live" or "Not Live" flight from list.
2. If user selects "Live", the airport code (stored in a different cell) is to show.
3. If user selects "Not Live", the airport code (stored in a different cell) is not to show.

I managed to put together an IF statement for the first leg, which just consisted of one flight, however I'm now struggling to find an efficient way for the other 5 sectors.

Example.

To make things a bit easier to understand, I will refer to each airport as A, B, C, D, E and F. In real life, these would be 3 letters, like Heathrow is LHR for example.

```
Sector 1 A-B - Not Live
Sector 2 C-D - Live
Sector 3 E-F - Not Live
Sector 4 F-E - Live
Sector 5 D-C - Not Live
Sector 6 B-A - Not Live
```

E-mail subject line format for above: C-D-F-E

I can for sure create the above off IF statements, however this would leave with: C-DF-E - If I was to work around it about put a hyphen at the end of D, then this wouldn't show correctly if the data was to change.

I need to stress that the "-" must separate each airport code but not at the start or end.

I hope you can help :)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question please.

Comment: please post the IF statement that you use. from your description, it is not clear how the data is arranged on the worksheet. for example, it is unknown how the sector 1,2,3,4,5,6 data is shown on the worksheet. how are the live/not-live choices made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather do this with VBA, but this does work:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tim! What a star! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you thank you!!